# show full Credit Card Information in Sales Email In Magento

Tags: magento-1.8

I receive credit card details in email like 4574xxxxx in email, but I want all the digit of credit card no in email, I don`t know which template is using for sending email. Please help for displaying full credit card no in email template.

Comment: Please don’t do that. Its a terrible practice that also involves private data from customers. Its not only terrible from the coding perspective but from the personal too, since i don know if i am shopping in your site and i dont want my credit card information to be unprotected. I think i would never say something like this, but you should stop programming since you clearly don’t know anything about minimal security measures. This is beyond coding and a huge risk to everyones security in the internet.

Comment: Its client requirement so I will have to to that.

Comment: Since no one with good intentions will need anyone else credit card, i will have to stick with my comment. Please dont give space to scammers or thieves

Comment: I can't stress this enough, **it is a terrible idea**. You can do it if you're using a solution integrated to magento by capturing the field, but if it's a 3rd party (say bank) system, then they'll never give it to you, no matter what.

Comment: Sometimes client requirements so egregiously criminally negligent with customer private information are a really good cause for you to drop the relationship and give them their money back.

Comment: Hi all, Even our customer wants something like this,  Is it possible to display last 8 credit card numbers instead of only last four. Our customer wants first half of credit card information in admin panel [slaes>orders ] and last half in "order email". Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Although its a bed Idea and we should suggest to client about not showing all digits, but only for knowledge I am posting the solution..

These digit can be manage with `app/code/local/Mage/Payment/Block/Info/Cc.php` .

Go to line 101 where you will see the code

`$data[Mage::helper('payment')->__('Credit Card Number')] = sprintf('xxxx-%s', $this->getInfo()->getCcLast4());`

change it to

`$data[Mage::helper('payment')->__('Credit Card Number')] = sprintf('%s', $this->getInfo()->getCcNumber());`

or according to your requirement.

**Please not :** Do not modify core file`s code from base folder, copy folder structure to local folder as I write and then use it.

Answer (score 5):

This is a seriously bad idea. This would play into the hands of fraudsters since email content will very likely be sent in plain text through the internets.

Comment: Yes I know but Its client requirement so I will have to to that.

Comment: I think your client will thank you if you talk them out of this. I can't think of a single reason why anyone would want to do this. The risks far outweigh anything.

Comment: Your customer will not thank you, but when things go south, will blame you for the data breach and fraudulent use of customer data that will occur down the road and attempt to drag you in to sharing any punitive damages tendered against them by local authority. If you think you can absorb the damage to your reputation, feel free to do it. You don't have to fulfill criminally negligent customer requirements. If I received such an email, I would do everything possible to determine where they have their merchant account and turn them in for breach of PCI. Punitive fines start at $20,000 USD.

Comment: I'm going to +1 Kristof and Fiasco,  this is definitely not recommended and the implications could be catastrophic for the developer. When, not if, this credit card data is compromised they will turn to you in the form of legal action.  Fines start at $20k,  and note, that is per credit card compromised.  What is the client requirement @Ashwani Panwar, there has to be a better way then plain text over email.  Is it because the client isn't processing c.c. data within Magento and inside an ERP?

Answer (score 1):

That's a terrible idea, don't do it! Try not to store credit card details at all and if you really really have to, always store it encrypted!

Comment: ok ! but from where..

Comment: Hi Ashwani , did you found some answer for this? please help me if you got any idea.... Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, I found it.